# explain unfamiliar python syntax -- returning into a list

Tags: python

I totally understand what the right side of this expression is doing.
But what's it returning into?  In other words, what's the left side doing?

```
[records, remainder] = ''.join([remainder, tmp]).rsplit(NEWLINE,1)
```

I'm not familiar with that syntax.

`remainder` is defined above this line as empty string:

```
remainder = ''
```

but `records` is not defined anywhere in the function.

From the context, it should be accumulating streaming content, but I'm not understanding how.

Comment: This is known as tuple unpacking. Actually the brackets are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`records` is taking the first element of the `rsplit`'s return value. `remainder` is taking the second.

```
% python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> foo = [3, 9]
>>> [records, remainder] = foo
>>> records
3
>>> remainder
9
>>> foo = [3, 9, 10]
>>> [records, remainder] = foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

You actually don't need the square-brackets around `[records, remainder]`, but they're stylistic.

Comment: This line of code is in a while true: loop, so it's declaring and filling "records" on each iteration of the loop--and then (a new) records is being overwritten (instead of accumulating) on each iteration and the old one trashed??  Sounds like you are saying the brackets do nothing??  So if I want to "accumulate" from the stream, I should do: upvalList.extend(records) on each iteration.  Thx 4 the fast response!

Comment: @Dewey Yes, `records` is a local variable if it's inside a loop. So using `foo.extend(records)` (where `foo` is a list defined and used outside the loop) would be a logical way to save the content of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It first [joins](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the content of `remainder` with the contents of `tmp` using an empty string as joiner.

```
''.join([...])
```

Then it [splits](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) this join from the right, using `NEWLINE` as splitter and only doing one split, that is, it returns two values, one from the beginning to the first occurrence of `NEWLINE` and another from there to the end.

```
.rsplit(NEWLINE, 1)
```

Finally it assigns the first value to `records` and the second to `remainder` using [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
a, b = (c, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about streaming content, but it's easy enough to try this for yourself:

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> b = '\ndef\nghi'
>>> c = (a + b).rsplit('\n', 1)
#['abc\ndef', 'ghi']
```

Then it uses unpacking to assign two variables (which should be written as):

```
fst, snd = c
```

(The `[]`'s are superfluous)